# Read and write image(large object) from postgres with qt

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, blob, large-data

I want to read and write large object like image or video in postgres with oid type with framework qt. In query i can using lo_import and lo_export to read and write largeobject with specific local address for import and export. But question is how can i read and write with qt and qsqlquery?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a table named *"my_table"*. For storing large binary objects with PostgreSQL it is recommended to use `bytea` type for a datafield, so name it *"binary_data"*.

To insert data I'd use `QSqlRecord`, like this:

```
QSqlTableModel *model;
QSqlDatabase m_database;
m_database = ...//connect to the database here
model = new QSqlTableModel(0, m_database);
model->setTable("my_table");
model->select();
QSqlRecord rec;
rec = model->record();
QFile f("path_to_a_big_file");
if(f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QByteArray ba = f.readAll();
    rec.setValue("binary_data",ba.toBase64());
}
model->insertRecord(-1,rec);
model->submitAll();
```

To update the data `QSqlQuery` will do:

```
QSqlQuery query(m_database);
query.prepare("update my_table set binary_data = :binary_data where [condition]....");
QFile f("path_to_a_big_file");
if(f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QByteArray ba = f.readAll();
    query.bindValue(":binary_data",ba.toBase64());
}
query.exec();
```

And finally to read the data you'll need to do something like this:

```
QSqlTableModel *model;
model = new QSqlTableModel(0, m_database);
model->setTable("my_table");
model->select();
 while(model->canFetchMore())
    model->fetchMore();
for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i)
{
    QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromBase64(model->record(i).value("binary_data").toByteArray())
    //do something with the retrieved data
}
```

Also note that it is your responsibility to remember the type of a file you put inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [server side SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html) for large objects, callable by `SELECT` statements through `QSqlQuery::exec()`.

To read or write a large object in one go, see `lo_get` and `lo_put`.

If the binary data are large enough that you'd rather process them by chunks, start a transaction, then use `lo_open`, `loread` / `lowrite` in a loop, `lo_close`...

The PostgreSQL type of the binary data sent and retrieved is `bytea`. `QSql::Binary` should be  used when binding input parameters with `QSqlQuery`, for the driver to escape the data accordingly when needed.